# Query Failed to Join two tables records into gridview

Tags: sql, sql-server, gridview

I am trying to join two tables by using SQL query by using single parameters. I have two tables student and student job record and I want to join this two table into single a single based on ID.

Student profile table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student_Profile]
(
    [StudentID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [First_Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Last_Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Qualifactions] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Name_Of_Instatutions] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [City] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Country] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Contract] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Here is the student job profile table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student_Job_Record] 
(
    [Record_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [StudentID] [int] NULL,
    [Total_Hours_Work] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Pay_Rate] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Total_Amount_Paid] [varchar](500) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I am using a stored procedure to display the data into gridview. Here is the stored procedure code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetStudentsDeatilsByID]
    @ID int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        Student_Profile.First_Name, Student_Profile.Last_Name,
        Job_Profile.Title, Job_Profile.Location, 
        Job_Profile.Type_Contract, Job_Profile.Salary
    FROM 
        Student_Profile, Job_Profile
    WHERE  
        Student_Profile.StudentID = @ID 
        AND Job_Profile.StudentID = @ID
END
```

I want to display and join this two table into gridview based on `studentID`. But when I enter the student Id and click the submit button, nothing is displayed.

Here is the screen shot when I run the applications.

[image]

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. If you do not have `StudentID` in `Job_Profile` then you can use `LEFT JOIN`.

```
Create proc [dbo].[spGetStudentsDeatilsByID]
@ID int
as
Begin
    SELECT 
    sp.First_Name, 
    sp.Last_Name ,
    jp.Title,
    jp.Location,
    jp.Type_Contract,
    jp.Salary
FROM Student_Profile sp
LEFT JOIN Job_Profile jp
ON sp.StudentID = jp.StudentID
WHERE sp.StudentID =@ID
End
GO
```

Comment: The multi-part identifier "Student_Profile.First_Name" could not be bound.

Comment: this is the error i am getting when i tried to execute it

Comment: query i execuations is fine but i am wondering why grid view is not displaying the data

Comment: @Mohammad did you try with `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: @Mohammad just replace `JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`, it may be the case where you do not have record for that student in one of the table.

Comment: Please give me a min

Comment: @Mohammad then use `LEFT JOIN` only.